# How to handle error in swift when server is not available?

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers, grpc

How to handle error for this server call when the server is not available or is down?

```
func createData(request:Crudpb_CreateRequest, with completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) throws {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.response = try! self.client.create(request) // <---- How to handle error for this server call when the server is not available or is down?
        completion(self.response.result)
    }
}
```

It returns an object, so when I store the result in response variable then say print(response.result) it prints the response string

Please help.

Comment: What error? Nobody knows which kind of errors `create(request` can throw. At least add a `do - catch` block to get an error rather than a crash

Comment: @vadian I already mentioned "when the server is not available or it is down"

Comment: Start by replacing `try!` with `try` inside a `do/catch`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't undertand what you are trying to do exactly, don’t know your entire code.

self.client is an object of what Class? What  self.client.create method returns? URLResponse?

Anyway, you can try:

```
if let response = self.response as? HTTPURLResponse{
    if response.statusCode == 503{
        //server not available
    }
}
```

After your `self.client.create` method.

Comment: It returns an object, so when I store the result in response variable then say print(response.result) it prints the response string.

Comment: The project uses HTTP/2 to connect to the server. Im using gRPC protobuf

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it via fetching http status code 503. This means that server is not available.

Comment: And BTW the connection is HTTP/2 type.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching `response.response?.statusCode`. If the code is 503, the server is unavailable. Note that if there are any errors, `statusCode` might not be available, so handle any `nil`s appropriately.