# How to not freeze the UI, and wait for response?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, protocol-buffers, grpc

I've been trying since the morning but I didnt achieve what I wanted.

I tried DispatchQueue.main.async and completion block but my "Submit" button in the UI still freezes waiting for the data to be returned from the server. This is my code:

```
func createData(request:Crudpb_CreateRequest, with completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) throws {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.response = try! self.client.create(request) // <---- How to handle error for this server call when the server is not available or is down?
        completion(self.response.result)
    }
}
```

I just noticed Im calling the 1st method from the following which is a Synchronous Unary which might be the reason behind the problem. But again I dont know how to call the second function in the fallowing:

```
 /// Synchronous. Unary.
  internal func create(_ request: Crudpb_CreateRequest, metadata customMetadata: Metadata) throws -> Crudpb_CreateResponse {
    return try Crudpb_CrudServiceCreateCallBase(channel)
      .run(request: request, metadata: customMetadata)
  }
  /// Asynchronous. Unary.
  @discardableResult
  internal func create(_ request: Crudpb_CreateRequest, metadata customMetadata: Metadata, completion: @escaping (Crudpb_CreateResponse?, CallResult) -> Void) throws -> Crudpb_CrudServiceCreateCall {
    return try Crudpb_CrudServiceCreateCallBase(channel)
      .start(request: request, metadata: customMetadata, completion: completion)
  }
```

Server Side Code:

```
func (*server) Create(ctx context.Context, req *crudpb.CreateRequest) (*crudpb.CreateResponse, error) {

    var result string
    firstName := req.GetAccount().GetFirstName()
    lastName := req.GetAccount().GetLastName()
    //  id := gocql.TimeUUID()

    fmt.Println("Triggered CREATE function on Go Server " + firstName + " " + lastName + "! Yayy!")

    result = fmt.Sprintf("id for %s %s : %s", firstName, lastName, strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(100)))
    return &crudpb.CreateResponse{
        Result: result,
    }, nil
```

I need this app / submit button not to freeze while it fetches result from server.

Please help.

Comment: Show the implementation of that `create` method.

Comment: Now show the implementation of that 2nd `create` method.

Comment: @rmaddy just updated the question with your request

Answer (score 1):

You are still performing work on the main thread.. `async` only makes the `createData()` method to return before the task is completed.. but **the task will still be processed at some time in the main thread and during this time your application will become unresponsive**.. try using a global queue instead.. to keep your main thread clean..

Dont forget to perform all your UI work on the main thread after getting your response.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check you now might have a full idea of what Im doing wrong.

Comment: I saw your edit.. I think my answer still solves your problem.

Comment: You know what funny thing is? If I use global queue in the following code I get the result but the UI gets updated like 5 seconds later (but I can see the print statement throwing the value in the xcode almost the same second I send the request to the  server) I cant paste complete code here so I will just give you screenshot link: http://prntscr.com/nmkyvt But when I use DispatchQueue.main.async for the same code it throws errors and nothing is sent to the server and nothing is received. This is too crazy for me.

Comment: If the response is not taking long.. and you UI is refreshing long after that.. I think that whatever you are doing with that data.. parsing, etc.. is taking longer than expected.. you could speed this process. lets say if you need to parse N objects.. try to process this concurrently in multiple tasks.. you could use a dispatch group for that.. that could help improve this time.

Comment: if you need more assistance maybe ping me on linkedin -> mrpatrnogic

Comment: Im not parsing any data as it doesnt need to be parsed because the data which is returned is purely a string and Im passing that string straight to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Use the asynchronous function instead and call the completion block inside `create` function's completion.

```
func createData(request:Crudpb_CreateRequest, with completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) throws { 
try! self.client.create(request) { (response: Crudpb_CreateResponse?, result: CallResult) in 
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
// This is assuming your completion involves UI operations. Otherwise there is no need for this async call.

let stringOutput = String(data: result.resultData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
    completion(stringOutput)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the question I have updated it.

Comment: But have you tried the way I've suggested to use the second `create` function? It is using the async function that should not freeze the UI

Comment: It shows this error if I use exactly the same code you showed: http://prntscr.com/nmda3o ... I tried and I get no string as a response, the result variable seems to show only status codes, description and a few other non string responses. And when I type "." after result I get this list: http://prntscr.com/nmdaph

Comment: At this point Im ready to pay to the one who fixes this problem.

Comment: The solution I've given above is for UI freezing problem. The `completion(result)` is simply passing the result back to the completion block. the type of `result` object is `CallResult`. From the screenshot you've uploaded it looks like there is a `resultData` property inside which is type `Data`. 

The server code looks like it' s just a formatted string
```
result = fmt.Sprintf("id for %s %s : %s", firstName, lastName, strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(100)))
```
I've updated my solution for sample converting of data. Feel free to experiment with properties

Comment: yes it returns the string. I used a new piece of code and it worked but the problem is the UI gets updated very late but the same response is printed in the xcode almost the same second.

Comment: I commented this on another answer: You know what funny thing is? If I use global queue in the following code I get the result but the UI gets updated like 5 seconds later (but I can see the print statement throwing the value in the xcode almost the same second I send the request to the server) I cant paste complete code here so I will just give you screenshot link: prntscr.com/nmkyvt But when I use DispatchQueue.main.async for the same code it throws errors and nothing is sent to the server and nothing is received. This is too crazy for me.

Comment: What I understood by the experiments so far is that "result" returns the response with regard to the connection status, any errors in connections etc and "response" is what we get then we can access the string response from the server by "response.result" it successfully showed the expected answer from server.

Comment: Okay, thats misleading from server api. But since you've figured that part out, refactor the example I've given with response.result and format it to get String output you're after. Without knowing what the type is, I can't advice what it is.   

Which error do you get when you put in `DispatchQueue.main.async `?

Comment: I tried your code and got this: http://prntscr.com/nmmii6 This confirms my theory that we are looking for response at the wrong place.

Comment: I would advice you to explore the values first of resulting objects using debugger breakpoints. This way you'd have better idea on whats going on and what available to use. If you have a network monitoring tool such as charles, try to see what data is coming from server and what format. Otherwise it's a lot of blind trial and error that can be frustrating.

Comment: The thing is the data shows up in the xcode almost the same second I make a request to the server but it is taking too long like 8 seconds to show up in UI. Something is wrong in the code thats why the UI update is getting delayed and I need to fix this.

Comment: I bought 2 Charles licenses one for Mac PRo and one for Macbook and now I think I cant see any request and response code because Im sing gRPC and the transfer is in binary form not json.

Answer (score 0):

Remove DispatchQueue.main.async block from the createData method

```
func createData(request:Crudpb_CreateRequest, with completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) throws {
    self.response = try! self.client.create(request)
    completion(self.response.result)
}
```

Use main queue only where you update the UI from the api response

```
myobj.createData(request: request, with: { string in
    print(string)//background thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = sting//main thread
    }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt help as I get the same result.

Comment: Please have a look at the question again as I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The UI freeze because you are doing too much work on the main thread. You should find out what function blocks the main thread. 
The instruments [time profiler](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/418/) is an easy way to see which function is spending too much time.

Comment: We already know what is taking long and it is the result from server

Comment: Okay, I see. But if you call server asynchronized, the UI shouldn't freeze.